# ArrayList of Integers value Addition? Can it be done?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have Created an ArrayList of Integers as follows:

```
ArrayList tiles_cell_nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tiles_cell_nums.add(0);
tiles_cell_nums.add(0);
```

Now I am trying to increment one of the values inside of the ArrayList as follows:

```
tiles_cell_nums.get(0) += 1;
```

But it is not letting me do that:

```
The Left side of an assignment must be a variable
```

So I am wondering, what is the easiest alternative for doing this?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
tiles_cell_nums.set(0, tiles_cell_nums.get(0) + 1);
```

Comment: Thank You very Much. Ill Set this as the correct answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

In `int i;`, `i` is a variable. Using `i` as a pointer allows you do do `i++`. However, you cannot directly use `tiles_cell_nums.get(0)++`.

```
final int i = tiles_cell_nums.get(0) + 1;
tiles_cell_nums.set(0, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is only one way I'm aware of to do such things:

```
ArrayList<int[]> intList = new ArrayList<>();

intList.add(new int[]{23});
intList.get(0)[0] += 1;

System.out.println("Number is: " + intList.get(0)[0]);
```

> Number is: 24

And no, it isn't easy nor pretty. You're better off with "primitive" collections provided by libraries like [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html) or [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). They come with all sort of collections that can hold primitive types and will be generally easier to use than ArrayLists of Integer (or any Number derived) objects.

My favorite is [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html), but you can try them and see which you like most (or which one has a licence that fits your requirements).

EDIT: To be clear, primitive collections won't save you from the set(get() + something) idiom. They're just generally easier to use than collections of boxed primitives.

Comment: Yeah, it could work. It would end up being worse than using java.lang.Integer though, given those are at least cached, and you wouldn't be able to use "+=" or "++" operators. Then again, the most sane way would be a primitive collection IMHO, even if you can't directly use operators with them.

Answer (score 0):

we can use listIterator(int Index) mehtod also, listIterator(0).next() help to take int Object.After addition performed we can set back to zero'th position.

```
tiles_cell_nums.set(0,tiles_cell_nums.listIterator(0).next()+1);
```

Comment: Is that the best thing you could say about your answer? Could you explain _why_ it works? Generally, answers with an explanation of the code and why they answer the question are significantly better.

Comment: @Ben hereafter I try to give an explaination. if I am  answering any question.